# Importing a file from outside directory Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I currently have a directory structure like so:

```
- App
-- Model
-- Controller
-- View
-- main.py
```

I want to import main.py into a class into a controller file for testing purposes. How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do relative imports in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an empty `__init__.py` file in the directory `App` to turn that directory into a *package*.

Then, provided the `/path/to/App` is visible in the `sys.path` of your python environment, you should be able to:

```
from App import main
```